# Build my Angular project without needing to specify long command options

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an issue with angular CLI. I want to build a project with long command: `ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing none`. Is there a way to create something like task in gulp and run that sequence of task with for example `ng build my-task`?

Comment: which version of angular do you use ?

Comment: I am using  angular 6

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Angular 6 you can tweak your angular.json according to your need.

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",<--none
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,<---false
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
```

alternatively you can modify existing build script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --prod",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Execute `npm run-script build` or `npm run build`